# Multi Auth login with single table user using middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created login application that uses two tables user and admin for login. The application is running properly with two different table. I have created two seperate views for admin login and user login and controllers for both the login is also different, but what i want is i don't want two seperate table (i.e. admin and user) i only want to include the role_type in user table only. Please help to sort out my issue. Here is my code :

> auth.php

```
return [


    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],


    ],


    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

> AdminLoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
    public function getAdminLogin() {

        if (auth()->guard('admin')->user()) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }

        return view('adminLogin');
    }
    public function adminAuth(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        if (auth()->guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        } else {
            dd('your username and password are wrong.');
        }
    }
}
```

> UserLoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserLoginController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
    public function getUserLogin() {
        return view('userLogin');
    }
    public function userAuth(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        if (auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
            $user = auth()->user();
            dd($user);
        } else {
            dd('your username and password are wrong.');
        }
    }
}
```

> AdminController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller {

    public function dashboard() {
        $user = auth()->guard('admin')->user();
        dd($user);
    }
}
```

> Kernel.php

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
    ];
}
```

> RedirectIfNotAdmin.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfNotAdmin {
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin') {
        if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('admin/login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

> Admin and User model :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

> Migrations:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email', 150)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

> For Admin Table:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email', 150)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
}
```

> View: (for admin)

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Admin Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.auth') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">E-Mail</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

> View for User Login:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">User Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('user.auth') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">E-Mail</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: You can create a role table. And you can add id of the role in users table. Then you can add any number of roles like admin editor user etc. So, you have all user data in user table. Use middleware for access restriction of different users

Comment: @Sagar Gautam: Can give me a link that fullfill my requirement because i'm new to laravel and searched a lot but cannot find any link relating to my requirement.

Comment: The above code is working but i want single table to manage all the roles

Comment: Whenever I see this sort of question I wonder why people don't use 3rd party libraries like [Spatie's Laravel Role-Permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) rather than re-inventing the wheel.